# Autohotkey Chrome IfWinExist Issue

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I want to have a sound repeat periodically when there is a new message in the Google Voice Inbox. So far what I've come up with is to have the GV Inbox always open in chrome, and have the following script running:

```
100:
IfWinExist, Google Voice - Inbox (
    SoundPlay, C:\Users\Terry's\Desktop\chimes.wav, wait
Sleep, 1000
Goto 100
```

If there is a new message, the title of the GV tab is "Google Voice - Inbox (1) - Google Chrome" and if there are no new messages, the "(1)" is missing, so that's why the search string for IfWinExist includes one a "(".

This only works, however, when the GV tab has the attention within chrome (it will work when chrome is minimized or another window is active, as long as GV is the selected tab within chrome). But if another tab within chrome has the attention, then it won't work, and I can't figure out how to make it work. I've tried Adjusting SetTitleMatchMode, but that's all I could come up with to mess with. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the AutoHotKey Windows Spy to see how the `GV` is identified? This is what you will need (and it will most probably be the string you already have) Then set SetTitleMatchMode to 2 (find string anywhere in title). You could try to experiment with "escaping" the "open bracket".

Please don't use Sleep but launch a timer. I temporarily changed the sound back to something I know works. Once this works, you can make a change back to SoundPlay and remove the MsgBox.

## Pseudo Code

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetTimer, CheckWin, 10000 ; Run CheckWin every 10 seconds.

CheckWin:
IfWinExist, Google Voice - Inbox (
{
    MsgBox, Alert
    SoundBeep, 700, 700
}
Return
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert. I had used Windows Spy to get the Window Title. I just copied your code into a new script, and it's still the same issue - it only works if the GV tab is the tab within chrome that has the attention. If any other tab is selected within chrome, IfWinExist doesn't seem to pick it up.

Comment: You wrote that it works when the right tab is selected, so the script does work already. How about `always` giving GV its `own` Chrome window with no other tabs in use?

Comment: Yeah, that would work. I feel like there should be something that I could do to make it work with having it as one of the tabs, but I probably should just accept it as a reasonable limitation of IfWinExist. I do like your suggestion to use SetTimer though - it seems like it works more cleanly.

Comment: To get a list of open tabs, you could check these discussions... http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/44832-retrieve-chat-history-in-windows-live-messenger/  AND  http://superuser.com/questions/106890/how-can-i-use-autohotkey-to-focus-on-an-existing-google-chrome-tab-not-a-conta

Comment: @jonsothin, Have you been able to get a list of all open tabs in Chrome to solve your issue?

Comment: @jonsothin, Maybe the TABS or EVENTS section could be helpful [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html)?

Comment: Thanks for following up Robert. Sorry I wasn't clear earlier - I'll just settle with keeping GV in it's own window - it's slightly less convenient that way, but it's not worth the time it'd take for me to see if there's a way I can make my original plan work. Thanks though!